# Failed to write session data

Tags: php, session

I received this message after long time of using the same application without programming changes:

```
Warning: Unknown(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Unknown(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

I thought is servers problem, but these messages are not showing in every computer. Is this some sort of problem with settings? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you're either out of disk space, or the folder where PHP stores session-files is write-protected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Bytes.com

> The filesystem containing `/tmp` is
>   full. Your system administrator should
>   fix this immediately - and if they
>   haven't noticed you ought to question
>   what level of support you're getting,
>   since a lot of things will go horribly
>   wrong if `/tmp` is full.

[Source](http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-php-o6gls9k2/)

Comment: not necessarily true. It could be a perms issue and there was a known bug in version(s) of PHP.